# "Финансовый достаток"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Подскажите, правильно ли словосочетание финансовый достаток. Если не совсем, или не верно, то какое слово больше подойдет к "финансовый"?
Такой же вопрос по "денежный".

Answer (score 2):

**Достаток** означает материальное благополучие *в целом* (с оттенком возможности длительного *потребления* благ, возможности позволять себе траты), поэтому не очень хорошо сочетается определениями, сужающими его до отдельных аспектов (здесь: наличие денег). Видимо, потому, что при этом *целому* как бы приписывается свойство *части*, которая без качественного изменения самого понятия может переходить из одной формы в другую и даже отсутствовать (достаток может проистекать и от успешного ведения натурального хозяйства) - традиционно понятию достатка придают "интегральный" смысл и не слишком конкретизируют его определениями. Можно говорить о **финансовой обеспеченности**, **независимости** и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

**ДОСТАТОК**, м. 1. Зажиточность, состоятельность. Семья среднего достатка. Иметь хороший (большой) достаток

Чаще говорят: **материальное  или  финансовое благополучие,  материальный достаток** (высокий или низкий), но выражения "денежный достаток, финансовый достаток, денежное благополучие также могут использоваться.

**Дополнение**

Достаток можно понимать как **достаточный уровень обеспечения** (чем?) финансами, деньгами или материальными благами. Вот и получается **финансовый достаток, денежный достаток, материальный достаток.**

Кроме того,  существуют **разные уровни** достаточности для бедных, для богатых, для семей со средним доходом, поэтому существительное "достаток" **может иметь дополнительные определения** (средний достаток, большой достаток).

Comment: Достаток в значении "достаточное количество чего-л" помечен в словарях как "разговорное".

Comment: Я не говорю, что это точное значение слова в современном языке (это значение приведено в словаре),  я говорю о родственных связях  и происхождении его современной семантики. Материал этот нужен для того, чтобы понять: может ли "достаток" сочетаться с определениями?